# How to make graphQL request with filter values?

Tags: javascript, graphql

after some struggling, I've managed to write some graphQL queries to provide data from my craft cms backend. The destination is an interactive map with leaflet.io .

At this moment, the starter queries are written inside their own javascript file.
But the user should be able to see results from the filtered data he asked for.
But I have no clue how to create a dynamic query that listens to a checkbox getting checked.. To make it all a bit more difficult, the filtered items are also graphQL based so using a query-selector is not an option while the nodes doesn't exist yet because of the async queries.

This is some code I have atm..

The boot query (gets all unfiltered data):

```
import { maps, customOptions } from "../leaflet.js";

export function bootThis() {
    const endpoint = 'ENDPOINT';

    const boot = 
    `
    fragment BootQuery on test_test_Entry {
        id
        crops
        country
        year
        testType
        lon
        lat
        specsTrial
    }
    query {
        entries(section: "test") {
            title
            ...BootQuery
        }
        entry(section: "countries") {
            title
            }
    }
    `

    fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_TOKEN'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ query: boot })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            document.querySelector( '.result_text > p').innerHTML = `${data.data['entries'].length}`
            data.data['entries'].forEach(element => {
                L.marker([element.lat, element.lon]).addTo(maps).bindPopup(
                    `
                    <strong>${element.title}</strong>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <p>${element.crops}</p>
                    <p><strong>${data.data['entry'].title}: </strong>${data.data['entries'].country}</p>
                    <p>${element.testType}</p>
                    <p>${element.year}</p>
                    <br/>
                    <p>${element.specsTrial}</p>
                    `, customOptions);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        })
};
```

My Country query (So the user can filter on countries).
For each entry, a div will be made with a checkbox, name and a label

```
export function loadCountries() {
    const endpoint = 'ENDPOINT';

    const countries = 
    `
    fragment AllCountries on countries_country_Entry {
        BE
        FR
        HU
        IT
        NL
    }
    
    query {
        entry(section: "countries") {
        title
            ...AllCountries
        }
    }
    `

    fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_TOKEN'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ query: countries })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            const form = document.getElementById('filter-form');
            form.appendChild(createCheckboxesFromObject(data.data['entry']));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        });

    
    function createCheckboxesFromObject(data) {
        const filterElement = document.querySelector('#country-container');

        let isFirstItem = true;
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
                if (isFirstItem) {
                    isFirstItem = false;
                    continue;
                }
            
                const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
                checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                checkbox.id = key;
            
                const label = document.createElement("span");
                label.textContent = value;
                label.setAttribute("for", key);

                const item = document.createElement("div")
                item.setAttribute('class', 'filter-item')
            
                item.appendChild(checkbox);
                item.appendChild(label);

                filterElement.appendChild(item)
            }
            return filterElement;
        }
}
```

The queries.js file where they all come together:

```
import { bootThis } from "./queries/boot.js";
import { loadCountries } from "./queries/country.js";
import { loadCrops } from "./queries/crop.js";
import { loadTrials } from "./queries/trial.js";

bootThis();
loadCountries();
loadTrials();
loadCrops();

// I want to write logic for the dynamic query here
```